# Custom Class as return in Iterator

Tags: c#

I have an extension method that iterates over a list of a POCO class with DateTimes.  This method then combines schedules that overlap or fall within a tolerance timespan of one another.  This works fine!

However, part of my need is to also get a list of the Ids (from DB) of the items combined for later reference.  I tried to convert my extension method to return my custom class but I get the following error:

```
Error   CS1624  The body of 'Extensions.Combine(CombinedSchedules)' cannot be an iterator block because 'CombinedSchedules' is not an iterator interface type
```

Here is my extension method:

```
        public static CombinedSchedules Combine(this CombinedSchedules items)
    {
        using (IEnumerator<ScheduleDto> enumerator = items.Schedules.GetEnumerator())
        {
            if (!enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                yield break;
            }

            var previous = enumerator.Current;
            while (enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                var next = enumerator.Current;

                if (TryCombine(previous, next, out var combined))
                {
                    items.IncludedSchedules.TryAdd(previous.Id);
                    previous = combined;
                    continue;
                }

                yield return previous;
                previous = next;

            }

            yield return previous;
        }
    }
```

Here is the CombinedSchedules class:

```
public class CombinedSchedules : IEnumerable<ScheduleDto>, IDisposable
{
    bool disposed = false;
    // Instantiate a SafeHandle instance.
    SafeHandle handle = new SafeFileHandle(IntPtr.Zero, true);

    public List<ScheduleDto> Schedules { get; set; }
    public List<int> IncludedSchedules { get; set; }



    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        return Schedules.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator<ScheduleDto> IEnumerable<ScheduleDto>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return Schedules.GetEnumerator();
    }

    #region IDisposable Support
    private bool disposedValue = false; // To detect redundant calls

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!disposedValue)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                // TODO: dispose managed state (managed objects).
            }

            // TODO: free unmanaged resources (unmanaged objects) and override a finalizer below.
            // TODO: set large fields to null.

            disposedValue = true;
        }
    }

    // TODO: override a finalizer only if Dispose(bool disposing) above has code to free unmanaged resources.
    // ~CombinedSchedules() {
    //   // Do not change this code. Put cleanup code in Dispose(bool disposing) above.
    //   Dispose(false);
    // }

    // This code added to correctly implement the disposable pattern.
    public void Dispose()
    {
        // Do not change this code. Put cleanup code in Dispose(bool disposing) above.
        Dispose(true);
        // TODO: uncomment the following line if the finalizer is overridden above.
        // GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
    #endregion
}
```

How can I get back all the things I need in order to later reference the list of combined schedules?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: It looks like your enumerator is using the class ScheduleDto.  So you custom class would need to inherit the ScheduleDto class.

Comment: Have you tried making your `Combine` extension method return an IEnumerable instead of just a single object

Comment: `public static IEnumerable<ScheduleDto> Combine(this CombinedSchedules items)` to start.

Comment: @Flydog57 I have.  The problem is, an IEnumerable<ScheduleDto> does not have the List<int> that I need of the combined schedule Ids.

Comment: @Zer0 Okay.  So I did that and now I'm getting errors from my yield return previous lines.  (Forgive me please, I'm still new to Enumerators.)

Comment: "_The problem is, an IEnumerable<ScheduleDto> does not have the List<int> that I need of the combined schedule Ids_" Something does not add up here with your code logic in your question. Your `Combine` extension method clearly yield returns ScheduleDto instances, so the result of this method would be an enumerable sequence of ScheduleDto instances, not a CombinedSchedules instance. You will need to rethink your approach, because your problem/conflict is not with code per-se, but with the logic you try to implement...

Comment: @elgonzo Exactly.  I know I need to rethink it, but I'm a bit stuck.  The whole Combine idea was from another StackOverflow question I asked.  Not sure how to get where I need to go.

Comment: What do you want to end with, what is your goal? You will have have to make a battle plan. Explain to yourself how this List<int> must/should relate to the ScheduleDto sequence provided by the iterator method. If you do that, you should have a clearer idea what you should do. I guess -- but i can't say for sure -- that you would need to create a new CombinedSchedules with some ScheduleDto instances selected and combined from the original CombinedSchedules object, with a matching List<int> too. If my guess is correct, then an iterator method with yield return would probably not be the way to go

Comment: @elgonzo Basically, This app evaluates schedules to see if they overlap. In the Combine method, I need to find out which ones get combined so that I can then iterate over those and add a db reference to the Combined schedule db entry that they belong to.  This is to allow future updates in case the schedule changes.

Comment: I suggest you turn your extension method from an iterator method into a "normal" extension method. Inside the method, ScheduleDto instances will be combined as well as their IDs processed as necessary, and a new CombinedSchedules object will be populated with those. Then just return the new CombinedSchedules object. Done. No more headaches with the iterator method.

Comment: @elgonzo I will try that.  You should add this as an answer as this is likely what I will do.  I would like to give you the credit for helping me so much.  Thank you.

Comment: @AaronRumford Why are you even doing this, why don't you just internally have a list of the values that you need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `Combine` method should return a new `CombinedSchedules` object, i would suggest to turn it from an iterator method into a "normal" extension method, more or less following this roughly outlined logic:

The extension method would enumerate over and combine the *ScheduleDto* instances from the provided original source *CombinedSchedules* object and also build a new *IncludedSchedules* collection along the way. With the combined *ScheduleDto*'s and the new *IncludedSchedules* collection, a new *CombinedSchedules* object will be created and returned.

Answer (score 4):

When you use `yield return` or `yield break` in a method, it *must* return `IEnumerable`, `IEnumerator`, or the generic versions. What happens here is the C# compiler rebuilds your method into the `MoveNext` method of an object that implements `IEnumerator` and `IEnumerable`.

The compiler doesn't know how to build a list, or a dictionary, or a string, or any other type that also implements `IEnumerable`.

Now, the feature you want is *possible*, and we know it is possible because C# 7 does so for `async` methods. In previous versions, `async` methods could only return `Task`, `void`, or `Task<T>` for the same reason, but in C# 7 the compiler team added the ability to supply your own "task builder" class.

The compiler team could in theory do the same thing for iterator blocks but the general feeling is that there's not much demand for the feature.

Your best bet then is to pick one of two strategies:

- Stick with your method that yields, and then write another extension method that turns a sequence into your data type.  See `ToList`, or `ToDictionary` or `string.Join` or any number of other methods that takes a sequence and returns an entirely different data structure derived from that sequence. This technique is useful if you are often in a situation where you need to construct a summary object from a sequence. The call site would be `combined.GetSchedules().Combine()` where `GetSchedules()` takes `CombinedSchedule` and returns `IEnumerable<Schedule>` and `Combine()` takes `IEnumerable<Schedule>` and returns `CombinedSchedule`.
- Stop yielding; create a CombinedScheduleBuilder object, and everywhere that you would yield, instead call the Add method on your builder. (yield breaks become returns.) The last thing your method does is return the thing that the builder built. This is useful for cases where you are simply transforming one object into another, which seems like a good match for your scenario. (This is basically the idea that the answer from elgonzo proposes.)